# C++ typedef WORD

Tags: c++

Каким образом можно определить тип WORD.
Необходимо, чтобы размер этого типа не зависел от архитектуры(32 или 64 бит)
Использование windows.h невозможно, так как пишется все под UNIX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int16_t WORD;
```

Comment: +1: `typedef` -- это в духе C++.

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, что вопрос, поставленный таким образом не имеет ответа.

Далее моя "компиляция" (выдержки) из книги "Ядро Linux. Описание процесса разработки" (просто недавно прочел, и думаю, цитаты будут к месту).

==

*Машинное слово* (word) - это количество данных, которые процессор может обработать за одну операцию. Когда говорят о n-разрядной машине, то чаще всего имеют в виду размер машинного *слова*. Например, когда говорят, что Intel Core i7 является 64-разрядным, то имеется в виду размер машинного слова, равный 64 разрядам, или 8 байтам.

Размер регистров вобщего назначения процессора соответствует размеру машинного слова этого процессора.

В ОС Linux размер виртуального адресного пространства соответствует размеру машинного слова, следовательно размер указателя равен ему.

Размер типа long языка C также равен машинному слову, тогда как размер типа int может быть меньше.

==

Т.е. по мнению писателей ядра Linux надо написать

```
typedef long WORD;
```

или

```
typedef unsigned long WORD;
```

Далее просто цитата из книги:

```
Слова, двойные слова и путаница в терминологии

В некоторых операционных системах и процессорах стандартную порцию данных 
не называют машинным словам. Вместо этого словом называется фиксированная 
порция данных, название которой выбрано случайным образом случайным образом
или имеет исторические корни. Например, в некоторых системах данные могут 
разбиваться на байты (byte - 8 бит), слова (word - 16 бит), двойные слова
(double word - 32 бит) и учетверенные слова (quad word - 64 бит), несмотря
на то, что на самом деле система является 32-разрядной. Подобная система 
наименований была принята в системах на основе Windows NT, а также в современной
Windows 7.
```

Таким образом, [[@Чистяков Владислав](/users/7136/%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2)](/users/7136/%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2), без уточнения для решения каких задач Вам нужен тип WORD, корректно ответить не получится.

Comment: Ну явно, что имеется в виду "стандартный" 16-битовый word

Comment: Да, я имел именно 16-битовый word. Но, спасибо за информацию

Comment: @Чистяков Владислав, так бы прямо и написали в вопросе.

Тогда самым очевидным и переносимым без дополнительных \#include будет

    typedef unsigned short WORD;

Answer (score 0):

Например, [так](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer):

```
#include <cstdint>

#define WORD uint32_t
```

Если ваш компилятор старый и не поддерживает C++11, используйте boost: `#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>` вместо `#include <cstdint>`.

Comment: @VladD, а вот у меня boost не знает WORD

    #include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
    
    int main ()
    {
    #if WORD
      WORD w;
    #else
      uint16_t w;
    #endif
    }

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst$ g++ -DWORD tt.cpp
    tt.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    tt.cpp:7:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘w’
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst$ g++ tt.cpp
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst$ echo $?
    0
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst$ 

Кстати, а почему Вы считаете, что WORD 32-bit?

Comment: @avp Я так понимаю, что `boost` здесь нужен для `uint32_t,` которого может не быть.

Comment: @avp: boost нужен только для `#include`, без `#define` (ну или `typedef`, как у вас) не обойтись. Размер `WORD` выбран произвольно, всё равно он должен быть машинно-независим. Если ТС нужно 64 или 16 бит, думаю, он сообразит, как поменять код.